# remove subsequent values in row in R

Tags: r, row, repeat

I want to remove a specific repetitive value in each row in the dataframe.
let's say:

```
DF (3*5)
#  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1  A  A  B  A  NA
2  C  C  A  A  B
3  B  A  A  NA NA
```

I want to remove subsequent A value.

```
so New_df:
#  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1  A  B  A  NA NA
2  C  C  A  B  NA
3  B  A  NA NA NA
```

P.S. Column 5(c5) can be removed because all NA value.
The point is to remove only subsequent 'A' value, and other subsequent values should not be changed (e.g. the second row has two 'C' which should not be removed).
How can I do it in R?

Comment: @zx8754 Because I am only concerning A and other values should not be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you entered these as character values rather than as factors. That way we don't need the additional step of running `DF[] <- lapply ( . , as.character)`.

```
 DF <- read.table(text = "
A  A  B  A  NA
C  C  A  A  B
B  A  A  NA NA", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It appears you only want the duplicated A's removed and shifted with the positions at the end replaced with NA's:

```
t( apply(DF, 1, function(x){ xR <- rle(x)
                      xR$lengths[xR$values == "A"] <- 1
                   x <- c( rep( xR$values, xR$lengths), 
                           rep(NA, length(x)-sum(xR$lengths) ) ) }
         )
   )

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "A"  NA   NA  
[2,] "C"  "C"  "A"  "B"  NA  
[3,] "B"  "A"  NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through rows, use *rle* and get values:

```
# example data
DF <- read.table(text = "
A  A  B  A  NA
C  C  A  A  B
B  A  A  NA NA")

data.frame(t(
  apply(DF, 1, function(i){
    res <- rle(i)$values
    length(res) <- length(i)
    res
  })))

# output
#   X1 X2   X3   X4   X5
# 1  A  B    A <NA> <NA>
# 2  C  A    B <NA> <NA>
# 3  B  A <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: thx for reply. but the point is to remove only repetitive A. other repetitive values should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after?

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) {
    idx <- which(x == "A");
    x[-idx[c(0, diff(idx) == 1)]];
})))
#  V1 V2   V3   V4
#1  A  B    A <NA>
#2  C  C    A    B
#3  B  A <NA> <NA>
```

---

### Sample data

```
DF <- read.table(text =
    "1  A  A  B  A  NA
2  C  C  A  A  B
3  B  A  A  NA NA", header = F, row.names = 1)
```

Comment: @Cina Not sure, you could try. You only want to remove duplicate `"A"`s, so somewhere you'll need a `x == "A"` condition, which you then use to remove the duplicates. I'm doubtful if using `unique` would give you a more succinct (or faster) solution.